# why strpos doesn't work with ">" and other chracters

Tags: php, strpos

I want to check whether special characters such as "<" ">" or the double quote itself is found in a string. But my function always return true.

Thank you

This is the code:

```
$name = "<h1><dfdafdfds";

function correctName($name){
    if (strlen($name) < 5 || (strpos($name, "<")===true) || 
    (strpos($name, ">")===true) || (strpos($name, "\"")===true)){

        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strpos either returns `false` or an integer value such as `5`. It does NOT return `true`.

Therefore `(strpos($name, "<")===true` always returns false.

your code evaluates as:

```
if (strlen($name) < 5 || false) || 
(false) || (false)){

    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

**You need to use this format:**

```
strpos($name, '<') !== false
```

so your code should look like:

```
if (strlen($name) < 5 || strpos($name, "<") !== false || strpos($name, ">") !== false || strpos($name, "\"") !== false) {
```

Comment: +1. In fact, I often see (`=== TRUE`) expressions when (`!== FALSE`) is required. Needless to say, these are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` never returns `TRUE`. It might return `FALSE`. Solution: change your comparisons to `!== FALSE`